# Why does 802.11ac TX speed on my Mac drop dramatically until I disconnect and reconnect

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, 802.11ac

I've recently got a new wireless router (TP-Link Archer VR400, latest firmware) which supports 802.11ac 5GHz 80MHz. I am literally 3 meters away from the router with perfect line of sight, and I live in a suburban area without any other 5GHz routers (to put in perspective there are just 3 2.4GHz other APs around that my Mac can discover with iStumbler). I've set my channel to 36 (otherwise it was randomly jumping around, becoming invisible, probably a misconfiguration with my location and channel regulations, then coming back while I'm still in front of my router, while 2.4GHz 802.11n from the same router is rock solid) and channel width to 80MHz (I'm planning to buy a NAS so I'm trying to get highest possible wireless speed).

Here is what I get when I first connect to my router:

[image]

Perfect. 867Mbps.

Then, after some time it drops drastically, sometimes giving up on 802.11ac and dropping back to 802.11n:

[image]

I've even seen it to drop to 7Mbps (yep, seven) when I'm literally in front of the router. In that case, Internet wasn't accessible. 7Mbps should be enough to open at least Google, but nothing opens, I can't even access the router's panel at 192.168.1.1. In that case I disconnect from the router, and reconnect, and voila, everything is at full speed again.

What might be happening?

Comment: Check your wireless power save settings. It sounds like classic symptoms to me. Either that or a bug in the driver. try updating the the cards driver.

Comment: Agreed with @Tim_Stewart, this could be related to Wireless power save.  Aside from updating your driver (and if you have another wireless PC), you could install wireshark and collect wireless captures in promiscuous mode on channel 36 (bond 80MHz) as the problem occurs.  This will tell us exactly what the problem is.  You can post it and I'll or We'll take a look at your capture.